# Separate every digit of number by comma in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

My String is like this

```
$str="12345"
```

I want to get

```
$str1 = "1,2,3,4,5"
```

Comment: @Nidhi The OP wants to separate with commas in the text, not convert to array.

Comment: But no harder use this: `implode(",",(str_split('123456')))`

Answer (score 1):

explose to an array with `str_split` and then `implode`

```
implode(str_split('testing'), ',')
```

will give you

```
t,e,s,t,i,n,g
```

samefor 1234

Comment: you wrongly use implode, here is the [manual implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: No both order are acceptable

Comment: putting array first hits the first `if` see source code, you win a comparison : https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/dd4a78b631b356beb8c7b5ab7f58a91008143d5a/ext/standard/string.c#L1308

Comment: Yeah, I see it. you're right.

Answer (score 0):

try this, check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/803896)**

```
implode(',', str_split($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$strLen = strlen($s);
$o = '';
for($i =0; $i < $strLen; $i++) {
      $comma = ($i < $strLen) ? ' , ' : '';
      $o .= $strLen[$i] . $comma;
 }
 echo $o;
```

Comment: Double check how you're handling the end of the string. Also, the OP didn't include spaces around the commas.

Answer (score 0):

Without explode or implode:

```
$str="123456789";
echo substr(chunk_split($str,1,","),0,-1);
```